# Cupping with a zero class can give a non-trivial class in cohomology with local coefficients?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology

I'm looking at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0792), where the authors state the following (highlighted)

[image]

Hopefully this gives enough context. Basically, the idea is that even though the homology class of a hypersurface $\Sigma$ is zero, it doesn't necessarily mean that the class $[\omega_\Sigma \otimes \tau]$ in cohomology with local coefficients obtained by tensoring a Poincare dual form $\omega_\Sigma$ of $[\Sigma]$ with a parallel section $\tau$ of some flat vector bundle is trivial.

I'm a beginner when it comes to algebraic topology (I know categories, sheaves, etc. but I guess I don't know a lot of basic algebraic topology) so this seems very weird to me from my point of view. Isn't this construction just a cup product? Shouldn't cupping with something that's zero (say if $[\Sigma]=0$ and hence $[\omega_\Sigma]=0$) give us zero?

Comment: Cup product with zero class is zero, but what you have here is not a cup-product of cocycles with local coefficients. Rather, the author defines here a cocycle with local coefficients by specifying a differential form with local coefficients: The expression $\omega\otimes \tau$ is such a form. And indeed, there are examples where $\Sigma$ is separating but the corresponding cycle is not a boundary. One way to think about this is that the "coefficient" of $\Sigma$ is a parallel section and this section does not extend to a parallel section on either one of the complementary components.